# Which PAT scopes for setting project avatar in azure devops?

Tags: azure-devops

I'm creating projects for azure devops with my web app and I'm having an issue with setting the project avatar. It works fine if I give the PAT full access but of course I would prefer not to have to do that but instead give the least scopes necessary.
But I don't know which ones that are and every time I try it I get an 'Unauthorized' error.

This is the Microsoft documentation for setting the avatar:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/avatar/set%20project%20avatar?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Could anyone tell me which scopes I need for setting the project avatar?

Comment: Please check if the answer below can resolve your issue, if yes, you could accept it as answer like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: I'm sorry, I just wasn't working yesterday and wasn't able to check the answer. As soon as I checked it I will accept the answer, please just give me some time to check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> which scopes I need for setting the project avatar?

Based on my test , you could grant the Token Administration(Read & manage) or Tokens(Read & manage) permission to the PAT.

[image]

Then the Rest API could work fine.

Answer (score 0):

The different scopes and their description are available in the [Authenticate with OAuth 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/get-started/authentication/oauth?view=azure-devops#scopes) documentation page (The same scopes are applicable for PAT tokens).

Sounds like the Scope you need is `vso.profile_write`, i.e User Profile Write

> Grants the ability to write to your profile.